# how to check if a session state has changed in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

hello i have 2 different aspx pages. Page 1 is the main page with a Textfield. Page 2 is another page were i can add members and its also in a frame of page 1.

In Page 2 i count the members and save it to a Session.

```
Dim anzahlExterneTeilnehmer As Integer = BookITVbSQL.SQLrunScalarBookit(externeTeilnehmerSQL)

Session("anzahlExterneTeilnehmer") = anzahlExterneTeilnehmer
```

The Textfield in Page 1 should show me the Result in the Textfield in realtime without refreshing the whole page.

i think that i need an event which checks the session for changes. is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no event that alerts of session changes - only session start and end events. You would need to take the proactive approach of manually polling from the client using AJAX.

Comment: could you give me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to rewrite page2 as a user control hosted within page 1.